# Menu and submenu PHP for Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, menu

I have a HTML structure and I want to change those menu elements for a WordPress Menu maintaining the class and id's, and I want to change these elements for the ones I obtain using `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` and `for each`, but don't know how.

The thing is changing all Categories for parent and subitem WP menu category and so on, until 5 level of depth that has the menu. For example, replace Devices with first item depth 0, inside change Mobile Phones for second level, and go changing.

```
<!-- mp-menu -->
                <nav id="mp-menu" class="mp-menu mp-overlap">
                    <div class="mp-level mp-level-open" data-level="1">
                        <h2 class="icon icon-world">All Categories</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                <a class="icon icon-display" href="#">Devices</a>
                                <div class="mp-level" data-level="2">
                                    <h2 class="icon icon-display">Devices</h2>
                                    <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                            <a class="icon icon-phone" href="#">Mobile Phones</a>
                                            <div class="mp-level">
                                                <h2>Mobile Phones</h2>
                                                <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Super Smart Phone</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Thin Magic Mobile</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Performance Crusher</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Futuristic Experience</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                            <a class="icon icon-tv" href="#">Televisions</a>
                                            <div class="mp-level">
                                                <h2>Televisions</h2>
                                                <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Flat Superscreen</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Gigantic LED</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Power Eater</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">3D Experience</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Classic Comfort</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                            <a class="icon icon-camera" href="#">Cameras</a>
                                            <div class="mp-level">
                                                <h2>Cameras</h2>
                                                <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Smart Shot</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Power Shooter</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Easy Photo Maker</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Super Pixel</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                <a class="icon icon-news" href="#">Magazines</a>
                                <div class="mp-level">
                                    <h2 class="icon icon-news">Magazines</h2>
                                    <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">National Geographic</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Scientific American</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">The Spectator</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">The Rambler</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Physics World</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">The New Scientist</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                <a class="icon icon-shop" href="#">Store</a>
                                <div class="mp-level">
                                    <h2 class="icon icon-shop">Store</h2>
                                    <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                            <a class="icon icon-t-shirt" href="#">Clothes</a>
                                            <div class="mp-level">
                                                <h2 class="icon icon-t-shirt">Clothes</h2>
                                                <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                                        <a class="icon icon-female" href="#">Women's Clothing</a>
                                                        <div class="mp-level">
                                                            <h2 class="icon icon-female">Women's Clothing</h2>
                                                            <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Tops</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Dresses</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Trousers</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Sale</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                                        <a class="icon icon-male" href="#">Men's Clothing</a>
                                                        <div class="mp-level">
                                                            <h2 class="icon icon-male">Men's Clothing</h2>
                                                            <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Trousers</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Sale</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="icon icon-diamond" href="#">Jewelry</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="icon icon-music" href="#">Music</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="icon icon-food" href="#">Grocery</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="icon icon-photo" href="#">Collections</a></li>
                            <li><a class="icon icon-wallet" href="#">Credits</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </nav>
                <!-- /mp-menu -->
```

Answer (score 0):

you can customize nav menu walker class of wordpress to put your N level HTML menu structure. Hers is a example of bootstrap nav walker

```
if (!class_exists('BootstrapBasicMyWalkerNavMenu')) {
class BootstrapBasicMyWalkerNavMenu extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{


    //Overwrite display_element function to add has_children attribute. Not needed in >= Wordpress 3.4
    /**
     * @link https://gist.github.com/duanecilliers/1817371 copy from this url
     */
    function display_element($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output)
    {
        if (!$element)
            return;
        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

        //display this element
        if (is_array($args[0]))
            $args[0]['has_children'] = !empty($children_elements[$element->$id_field]);
        else if (is_object($args[0]))
            $args[0]->has_children = !empty($children_elements[$element->$id_field]);
        $cb_args = array_merge(array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
        call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_el'), $cb_args);

        $id = $element->$id_field;

        // descend only when the depth is right and there are childrens for this element
        if (($max_depth == 0 || $max_depth > $depth + 1) && isset($children_elements[$id])) {

            foreach ($children_elements[$id] as $child) {

                if (!isset($newlevel)) {
                    $newlevel = true;
                    //start the child delimiter
                    $cb_args = array_merge(array(&$output, $depth), $args);
                    call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_lvl'), $cb_args);
                }
                $this->display_element($child, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth + 1, $args, $output);
            }
            unset($children_elements[$id]);
        }

        if (isset($newlevel) && $newlevel) {
            //end the child delimiter
            $cb_args = array_merge(array(&$output, $depth), $args);
            call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_lvl'), $cb_args);
        }

        //end this element
        $cb_args = array_merge(array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
        call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_el'), $cb_args);
    }// display_element


    /**
     * @link https://gist.github.com/duanecilliers/1817371 copy from this url
     */
    public function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) 
    {
        if ((is_object($item) && $item->title == null) || (!is_object($item))) {
            return ;
        }

        $indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';

        $li_attributes = '';
        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        //Add class and attribute to LI element that contains a submenu UL.
        if (is_object($args) && $args->has_children) {
            //$classes[] = 'dropdown';
            $li_attributes .= ' data-dropdown="dropdown"';
        }
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        //If we are on the current page, add the active class to that menu item.
        $classes[] = ($item->current) ? 'active' : '';

        //Make sure you still add all of the WordPress classes.
        $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item, $args));
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"';

        $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args);
        $id = strlen($id) ? ' id="' . esc_attr($id) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . $li_attributes . '>';

        //Add attributes to link element.
        $attributes = !empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .=!empty($item->target) ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .=!empty($item->xfn) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr($item->xfn) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .=!empty($item->url) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= (is_object($args) && $args->has_children) ? ' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"' : '';

        $item_output = (is_object($args)) ? $args->before : '';
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        $item_output .= (is_object($args) ? $args->link_before : '') . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . (is_object($args) ? $args->link_after : '');
        $item_output .= (is_object($args) && $args->has_children) ? ' <span class="caret"></span> ' : '';
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= (is_object($args) ? $args->after : '');

        $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
    }// start_el


    public function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) 
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu dropdown-menu\">\n";
    }


}
}
```

How to use this,

```
 <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'your-menu-location', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav', 'walker' => new BootstrapBasicMyWalkerNavMenu())); ?>
```

Hope this will helps you.

For more information,

- [Understanding the Walker Class](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-walker-class--wp-25401)
- [WP Bootstrap Navwalker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)
- [Custom Nav Menu Walker Function](http://shinraholdings.com/62/custom-nav-menu-walker-function/)